# Scrapy 1.0: How to run crawler in Celery?

Tags: python, scrapy, celery

I tried the sample from document http://doc.scrapy.org/en/stable/topics/practices.html, but there would be an error **ReactorNotRestartable** while running it a second time.

```
settings = get_project_settings()

runner = CrawlerRunner(settings=settings)

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    yield runner.crawl(LatestNewsSpider)
    reactor.stop()

def run_spider():
    crawl()
    reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD` to 1 in your Celery settings. This will run only one task in each child process, so that it will never start the reactor more than once in the same process.

Alternatively, you could run the reactor in a thread and never stop it. I have no idea if it would work. [crochet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/crochet/0.8.1) might be of use.

Comment: Tweaking of `CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD` didn't work for me